# Inefficient/ugly replacement function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, replace, ecmascript-6

I wrote a function that is supposed to replace code in between of two delimiters with the value, it returns (The string I'm applying this to is the .outerHTML of a HTML-Object).

This will be used similar to how it is used in e.g. Vue.js or Angular.

It looks like this:

```
static elemSyntaxParse(elem) {
        let elem = _elem.outerHTML;
        if (elem.includes("{{") || elem.includes("}}")) {
            let out = "";
            if ((elem.match(/{{/g) || []).length === (elem.match(/}}/g) || []).length) {
                let occurs = elem.split("{{"),
                    key,
                    temp;

                for (let i = 1; i < occurs.length; i++) {
                    if (occurs[i].includes("}}")) {
                        key = occurs[i].substring(0, occurs[i].indexOf("}}"));
                        temp = eval(key) + occurs[i].substring(occurs[i].indexOf("}}") + 2);
                        out += temp;
                    } else {
                        ModularCore.err("Insert-Delimiters \"{{\" and \"}}\" do not match.");
                        break;
                        return elem;
                    }
                }
                return occurs[0] + out;
            } else {
                ModularCore.err("Insert-Delimiters \"{{\" and \"}}\" do not match.");
                return elem;
            }
        }
        return elem;
    }
```

(The function is inside of a class and refers to some external functions.)

Example use:

```
<body>
    <p id="test">{{ Test }}</p>
    <script>
        let Test = 27;
        document.getElementById("test").outerHTML = elemSyntaxParse(document.getElementById("test"));
    </script>
</body>
```

Returns this string:

```
<p id="test">27</p>
```

It works but it is rather ugly and kinda slow.

How would I go about cleaning this up a bit? I am open to ES6.

PS: I now "eval() is evil" but this is the only occurrence in my code and it is (as far as i know) not replaceable in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post this on CodeReview instead.

Comment: The `if (elem.includes("{{") || elem.includes("}}"))` looks really superfluous.

Comment: I need this in order to check if there even is something to replace (Performance - why do all of the work for no reason). If I were to use "&&" it would just skip everything and not catch the "no match" error if for example there would only be one of those tags.

Comment: @JonasKarg `includes` isn't much faster than `split`, especially when the string is not found. I think it is much more important to a) keep the code simple and b) don't do the work twice if the match is found. (Also don't do it using three different methods - `includes`, `match` and `split`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can omit a few checks and end up at:

```
 const text = elem.outerHTML.split("{{");
 let result = text.shift();

 for(const part of text) {
   const [key, rest, overflow] = part.split("}}");
   if(!key || rest == undefined || overflow) {
     ModularCore.err("Insert-Delimiters \"{{\" and \"}}\" do not match.");
     return elem.outerHTML;
   }

   result += eval(key) + rest;
 }

 return result;
```

Comment: Ill still have to add a better error-catching mechanism because if it gets a invalid input, my entire program errors out. But except from that - works great and is fast.

Comment: @jonas glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Invert the testing logic to get rid of nesting and `else` clauses

---

```
    if (! elem.includes("{{") || !elem.includes("}}")) {
       ModularCore.err("Insert-Delimiters \"{{\" and \"}}\" do not match.");
       return elem;
    }

    // original loop code here
```

---

Don't double check - as [@Bergi comment says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804480/inefficient-ugly-replacement-function#comment86623843_49804480).

test for return values indicating "not found, etc"

```
// if is removed. next line...
let occurs = elem.split("{{"), key, temp; 

// if the separator is not in the string, 
// it returns a one-element array with the original string in it. 

if(occurs[0] === elem) return "no substring found";
```

---

The above should eliminate 2 nesting levels. You can then do a similar thing in that inner `for` loop.

---

Simplify compound logic.

`!a || !b` is equivalent to `!(a && b)`.  [This is De Morgan's law](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/)